# WPF - How to display a tooltip on a hyperlink only when the hyperlink is disabled

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hyperlink, tooltip

This is a more specific description of my problem [from a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280282/wpf-tooltip-on-a-disabled-hyperlink-with-an-embedded-textblock-element), with a follow-up answer.

I had a standard hyperlink defined in XAML:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink IsEnabled="{Binding LinkEnabled}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

The hyperlink's IsEnabled property is bound to a property on the view model, the value of which can change. I needed to place a tooltip on the hyperlink which would only be displayed if the hyperlink is disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show the tooltip only when the hyperlink is disabled, [the ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled and ToolTipService.IsEnabled (with the negation converter) properties must be set on the hyperlink:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12975309/344985)

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink IsEnabled="{Binding LinkEnabled}"
               ToolTip="ToolTip"
               ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
               ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource negateConverter}}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

However, the tooltip won't be shown, since once the hyperlink is disabled, [it stops being hit-testable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280282/wpf-tooltip-on-a-disabled-hyperlink-with-an-embedded-textblock-element#comment39408123_25280282), because it is contained in the TextBlock (or so I understood).

Thus, the solution would be to change the "IsEnabled" property on the parent TextBlock, not on the hyperlink.
However, this works:

```
<TextBlock IsEnabled="False">
```

But this doesn't:

```
<TextBlock IsEnabled="{Binding LinkEnabled}">
```

In the latter case, [changing the TextBlock's IsEnabled property will not change the hyperlink's IsEnabled property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4445407/344985). To solve this issue, [the hyperlink's IsEnabled property must be bound to the parent's property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6215696/344985).

**And here is the actual solution, all put together:**

```
<TextBlock IsEnabled="{Binding LinkEnabled}">
    <Hyperlink IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}"
               ToolTip="ToolTip"
               ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
               ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type FrameworkElement}}, Converter={StaticResource negateConverter}}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```